# Tab Controls and their child windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, user-interface

I'm using a control tab (Windows class "SysTabControl32") to organize GUI elements in an application I'm developing. In the past I've captured the TCN_SELCHANGE event and then, on a per GUI element basis, decided what should be visible or not. This is quite fine for small applications with only dozens of GUI elements, but my current project is more complex.

I'm hoping there is an easier solution. What I'd like to have is the tab control with multiple tabs. Each tab will have a GUI element "wrapper" that I can show/hide individually and have all the corresponding child elements become visible/hidden. I have read that I should use dialogs to do what I'm describing, but cannot find any examples.

Are dialogs the way to go? If so where can I find a simple example? If not, what should be done here?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more productive to use a widget library that wrapped all this up for you. Coding against raw Win32 is like programming in assembly.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I happen to be programming in assembly. C/C++ tags are for more exposure since the same thing applies. I'm not sure if that validates your point or makes it moot...

Comment: Are you some sort of programming masochist?!!  ;-)

Comment: @David Heffernan: Indeed sir. I program while walking across a bead of hot coals and have razor blades glued business end up on all my keys. I program in assembly for fun when I'm not writing in pure binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Tiib and Tergiver for the answers, unfortunately I just don't like either of those solutions. Here's what I decided to do:

When a new tab is added to my tab control, I create a window with the BUTTON class and the BS_OWNERDRAWN style. Then I replace the windows procedures (GWL_WNDPROC) with my own version (forgive my assembly):

```
ForwardMessageProc proc hWnd:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM
  .switch uMsg
    .case WM_NOTIFY
      invoke            WinProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam
      xor               eax, eax
      .break
    .case WM_COMMAND
      invoke            WinProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam
      xor               eax, eax
      .break
    .default
      invoke            DefWindowProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam
      .break
  .endswitch
  ret
ForwardMessageProc endp
```

All it does is forward GUI messages to the parent window. These "tab frames" will be the actual content area of the tabs so I add all GUI elements to these tab frames directly. Then, when a user clicks on the tab, I can show/hide each tab frame individually and the GUI elements that are on it will follow suit. So far everything is working perfectly and I haven't found any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Property Sheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774538%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Maybe these solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN is always a good place to start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760551.aspx#creating_tab_dialog_box

Comment: Thank you. My google-foo was not working for me... or was the bing-foo?